# python pth file import statements ineffective?

Tags: python

The import statements executed from the pth files seem to execute fine. But I don't seem to be able to access any of the modules that are imported in this way.

What is this sorcery?

Comment: what is the curse blocking you from adventuring further in this dangerous quest? (or, for the records: what's the faulty code? what's the error you're having?)

Comment: @Samuele As I said, the modules imported in the pth files do not become available in the code.

Comment: please, elaborate: "don't seem to be able to access". What is the full traceback? `.pth`-files might change what modules you can import but to access a module you need to import it in your code explicitly. To affect anything, `.pth`-files should be in directories recognized by site.py (`site.getsitepackages()`, `site.getusersitepackages()`, `site.addsitedir()`).

Comment: pth files are only links to other python-sources. they are no source.

Comment: @Sebastian Well, pth files support the import statement. What is that for then, if the modules imported using the statement are not available to me in the code. There is no traceback. Just the names from the module remain undefined. Why do I have to explicitly import them again? I am OK with doing that, BTW. Just want to understand the idea behind the import statements in the pth files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your comments I'm guessing that you're getting NameError exceptions for some modules due to confusion about the purpose of `.pth`-files.

`pth` stands for `path`. The purpose is to add paths to `sys.path` (pythonpath - path that Python uses to find modules during import).  See [`site` module documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/site.html).

The lines that start with `import` can contain any code but generally they modify `sys.path`. For example, `setuptools` machinery:

```
import sys; new=sys.path[sys.__plen:]; del sys.path[sys.__plen:]; p=getattr(sys,'__egginsert',0); sys.path[p:p]=new; sys.__egginsert = p+len(new)
```

Another common case is when `.pth`-files are used to implement ["namespace" packages](http://peak.telecommunity.com/DevCenter/setuptools#namespace-packages):

```
import sys,types,os; p = os.path.join(sys._getframe(1).f_locals['sitedir'], *('zope',)); ie = os.path.exists(os.path.join(p,'__init__.py')); m = not ie and sys.modules.setdefault('zope',types.ModuleType('zope')); mp = (m or []) and m.__dict__.setdefault('__path__',[]); (p not in mp) and mp.append(p)
```

`.pth`-files are not there to make module names appear in your code. To import `some_module`, add at the top of each module where you want to use it:

```
import some_module
```

Comment: That is what I am trying to get some insight on. You can already add to the path by adding the corresponding lines to the pth file. Then what is the purpose / thought behind allowing the import statement? What problem is it intended to solve? What use case does it cater to?

Comment: @Ziffusion: I've added use cases for `import` inside `.pth`-files

Comment: @Ziffusion The problem it solves is that you can then use that module in your code.

Comment: @Marcin Not sure if you read the question :) Because that is exactly what I am saying does NOT happen. You cannot use the modules imported in pth files in your code. Have you been able to do this?

Comment: @Ziffusion I read the question. It doesn't actually have any code or anything else to demonstrate your problem. The point of the import is that you can use the module once you have imported it. You cannot use it before you have imported it.

Comment: @Marcin OK. So, you are saying that once you use the import statement in the pth file, you can then use the module in your code. Am I reading this correctly? What I am trying to point out is that the question states exactly the problem with this. That it does not work that way. Have you ever tried this by the way? I mean, use the import statement in the pth file and then try and use the module? I'd like to know if it worked.